# Minecraft Server: Connection refused

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, hosting

My Minecraft Server is running perfectly and I can connect.
But, if others try, it says "Can't connect: connection refused: connect".

I have a Mac, with 8GB RAM and am using Rcon. I connect using localhost.
I can't even connect with telnet!

Comment: Have you checked your firewall settings?

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185047/unknown-host-bukkit-1-7-10/185230#185230)! Your point should be solved with **Is it possible to connect through the Internet?**

Comment: canyouseeme is great.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible things:

1. Have you port forwarded. You must do that if you are going to connect with an external ip. This is configuring your router's firewall to let connections to that port through. A great tutorial [here](http://www.macworld.com/article/2081139/how-to-set-up-port-forwarding.html).But remember: (A)You need to configure port `25565` and (B) Your external ip address will change so tell everybody and you may have to update config.

   2. Have you given your people the `external` ip. That is if you go to [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ip&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=dGotVa04wsfyB4XHgegC) google will tell you your `Public IP`

Hope This Helps,
1st post on Arqade!

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to connect via localhost, but others are not able to connect to your machine, I'd recommend checking two things:

1. Your firewall: This is likely going to be the culprit. Make sure that you're allowing minecraft.exe through your firewall, and that you're accepting incoming requests on port 25565 (or whatever port you're using for your server).
2. Your router: Check and make sure there are no ports being blocked on the router level. Sometimes routers have a high security setting, and lowering this allows others to connect.